# what is new design library in new android studio version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

In a new version of android studio there are a new libraries that's replaced with libraries of old versions.

In **android studio 3.5.0** what the library of design like that

```
dependencies{

  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0' 
}
```

Comment: It is not related to Android Studio, it is related to new version of Android. [Use implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

Answer (score 0):

@Mohamed Maher,

Library versioning is the different thing which is not related to Android Studio, Yes but if you are upgrading version of your Gradle dependency then it might be a problem.

Your above library version is dependent on your install build tool which is defined in your app-level Gradle, Read bellow link it maybe helps you

[Support Library setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup)

Like my `buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'`

Then my Dependancy is like
`implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`

Also, one more thing if you are using `androidX` then it will be different

Comment: No. It is not correct. I can use buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' and build a project with appcompat-v26.